# Invertion of linear system and metric derivatives

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I'm trying to generate a grid for CFD computations following the steps in [this document](http://www.nada.kth.se/kurser/kth/2D1263/l2.pdf). However I'm having problems to derive the expressions for ${\partial f(x,y) \over \partial x(r,s)}$ and ${\partial f(x,y) \over \partial y(r,s)}$ which are given in the following section:

> By use of the chain rule,
>   \begin{equation}
> {\partial f \over \partial r} = {\partial x \over \partial r}{\partial f \over \partial x}+{\partial y \over \partial r}{\partial f \over \partial y}\\
> {\partial f \over \partial s} = {\partial x \over \partial s}{\partial f \over \partial x}+{\partial y \over \partial s}{\partial f \over \partial y}
> \end{equation}
>
> which is inverted as a linear system of two unknowns to become
>
> \begin{equation}
> {\partial f \over \partial x} = {1 \over D}\Big({\partial y \over \partial s}{\partial f \over \partial r}-{\partial y \over \partial r}{\partial f \over \partial s}\Big)\\
> {\partial f \over \partial y} = {1 \over D}\Big(-{\partial x \over \partial s}{\partial f \over \partial r}+{\partial x \over \partial r}{\partial f \over \partial s}\Big)
> \end{equation}
>
> where
>
> \begin{equation}
> D = {\partial x \over \partial r}{\partial y \over \partial s}-
>     {\partial y \over \partial r}{\partial x \over \partial s}
> \end{equation}

I have tried to solve for ${\partial f \over \partial x}$ in the first two equations and then combine the results to get Eq. 3 but I have failed in my attempts. I have also tried to solve for ${\partial f \over \partial y}$ in the first two equations but I cannot obtain Eq. 4.

**Related question:** In the same document the author refers to the derivatives

$$ {\partial x \over \partial r}, {\partial x \over \partial s}, {\partial y \over \partial r},\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ {\partial y \over \partial s}$$

as "metric derivatives" and I would like to know why these derivatives bare such a name. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've missed a minus sign in your expression for $\partial f/ \partial y$, this is just what you get from the cofactor formula for the inverse of a $2 \times 2$ matrix: letting $$M = \left(\begin{matrix} x_r& y_r \\ x_s & y_s \end{matrix}\right),$$

we have

$$M^{-1} = \frac1{\det M}\left(\begin{matrix} y_s& -y_r \\ -x_s& x_r \end{matrix}\right),$$ and $\det M = x_r y_s - y_r x_s$.

Comment: This answer was useful, and thank you for noting the missing minus sign in my original post.